# UIPickerView as inputView not hiding on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uitextfield, uipickerview, inputview

I have added `UIPickerView` as `inputView` to `UITextField` in my app. It works perfectly on iPhone, but when I run the same code on iPad, my pickerView does not hide on clicking `done` button.
Some code:

```
picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.dataSource = self;
[picker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
self.someInput.inputView = provincePicker;

UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
    target:self action:@selector(inputAccessoryViewDidFinish)];
[pickerToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:doneButton] animated:NO];
self.someInput.inputAccessoryView = pickerToolbar;
```

What do I have to change (add?) to make picker disappear?

edit: `inputAccessoryViewDidFinish` is my method, it just calls

```
[self.someInput resignFirstResponder]
```

Comment: Is inputAccessoryViewDidFinish your method?

Comment: yes, I have just updated question adding information about it

Comment: Does the toolbar come on the picker all right?

Comment: See my edit in my answer

Comment: It displays properly. I know I should avoid setting absolute values here, but it's just begining of making my app compatible with iPad, I will work this out later.

Comment: Use a breakpoint and see if inputAccessoryViewDidFinish gets called.

Comment: And also does make sure inputAccessoryViewDidFinish is spelled correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)inputAccessoryViewDidFinish

{
   [self.someInput resignFirstResponder];
}
```

**EDIT:** Implement -disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal and return NO. That should alllow the keyboard to dismiss.

Comment: I do not understand, why toolbar is supposed to be `UIPicker`s inputview. In addition, xcode does not allow me to change `UIPicker`s `inputView` property, as it's readonly. Also, xcode says, that my `UITextField` has no selector named `resignFirstController`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `UIPopOverController` to achieve the same results.

[This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29472/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uipopovercontroller-tutorial) tutorial can get you started.

Comment: Reason for the downvote? I do believe for the functionality the OP is trying to implement, the `UIPopOverController` is more appropriate.